# General way to find orders of reduced residue classes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm curious if, given an integer $n$, there is a general method for finding the *orders* of the reduced residue classes modulo $n$, as well as *how many* reduced residue classes correspond to each order.

I take $n=663=3\times13\times17$ as an example. There are $\phi(663)=\phi(3)\phi(13)\phi(17)=384$ reduced residue classes $\pmod{663}$.

Further, $\lambda(663)=\text{lcm}(\phi(3),\phi(13),\phi(17))=48$, which means any any reduced residue has order at most $48$.

However, I'm wondering if I can get more information; namely,

- All the possible orders of reduced residue classes $\pmod{663}$;
- How many reduced residue classes there are for each order.

> For what it's worth, a computer script gives that the possible orders are `{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 48}` and
>
> ```
> 1 reduced residue classes of order 1
> 7 reduced residue classes of order 2
> 2 reduced residue classes of order 3
> 24 reduced residue classes of order 4
> 14 reduced residue classes of order 6
> 32 reduced residue classes of order 8
> 48 reduced residue classes of order 12
> 64 reduced residue classes of order 16
> 64 reduced residue classes of order 24
> 128 reduced residue classes of order 48
> ```

I chose $663$ as an example but my primary question is about how to determine these facts in general. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb Z/663\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/17\mathbb Z$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Hi, I'm aware of this fact, though I'm not sure how exactly to use it ... would you be able to elaborate?